# Graphing with separate hour and date in R

Tags: r, graphics

I have a table as follows

```
hour  reading   date
22    197       6/20/13
23    231       6/20/13
0     25        6/21/13
1     210       6/21/13
2     17        6/21/13
```

What would be the best way for me to graph this data?

Should I combine the hour and the date columns into a single datetime column?

Comment: Seeing as this comment is on hold, could I ask where it would be appropriate to ask for questions related to best practices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Structured types are almost always superior for analysis tasks, because they will be understood intrinsically by other commands, like `plot`.

An R package called `lubridate` is useful for doing time manipulation, but base R is sufficient for the task at hand.

```
dfs <- 'hour    reading date
22  197         6/20/13
23  231         6/20/13
0   250         6/21/13
1   210         6/21/13
2   173         6/21/13
'
df <- read.table(text=dfs, header=T)
```

Then we add the time column using the function `strptime`.  `strptime` takes a format string (see `?strptime` for information) for parsing a date into a `POSIXlt`, which is one of R's internal datetime classes.  We then add on the number of hours (the + operator takes a number of seconds, so we multiply by 3600):

```
> df$time <- strptime(as.character(df$date), "%m/%d/%y") + 60 * 60 * df$hour
> df
  hour reading    date                time
1   22     197 6/20/13 2013-06-20 22:00:00
2   23     231 6/20/13 2013-06-20 23:00:00
3    0     250 6/21/13 2013-06-21 00:00:00
4    1     210 6/21/13 2013-06-21 01:00:00
5    2     173 6/21/13 2013-06-21 02:00:00
```

Then we can plot away and the axis will be formatted nicely.

```
plot(reading ~ time, data=df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 

Would it be possible for you to talk through this line:
strptime(as.character(df$date), "%m/%d/%y") + 60 * 60 * df$hour

Comment: Added more information about `strptime` to the body

Answer (score 0):

Combining into a single date time would be a good option.

```
plot(x=1:length(df$date),y=df$reading, xaxt='n')
axis(side=1, at=1:length(df$date), label=paste(df$date,df$hour,sep="-"))
```

Comment: This works well enough for most purposes so long as the data is at regular intervals; otherwise it can be deceptive.

Comment: Excellent point! I should have made that clear.